# There should be one and only one value in column B for every value in column A - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, great-expectations

I have a data frame as shown in image:

[image]

I want an output similar to the `Value` Column.
What it means is for every value in column `A`, there can only be one and only one value in column `B`.
Even if value in column `A` repeats, the value in column `B` should also repeat.
Please help

Comment: Instead of a screenshot of data, could you replace it with the code that creates the actual data frame?

Comment: Seems like you need to group your data by column A and take the column B.  Then you can apply some methods, like median. In this case, method *first* can do the trick.  But it would be nice if you provided some data.

Comment: thanks guys..For the help

Comment: This is not a great-expectation related question. I would suggest removing that tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.transform.html) to set the first 'B' value encountered for each 'A' value to each row then test if this first value is equal to 'B' value.

```
df['V'] = df['B'] == df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('first')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   A  B      V
0  1  a   True
1  1  a   True
2  2  a   True
3  3  b   True
4  1  a   True
5  2  b  False
6  3  c  False
7  1  d  False
```

Details:

```
>>> df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('first')
0    a
1    a
2    a
3    b
4    a
5    a
6    b
7    a
Name: B, dtype: object
```